# Rails relationship for a single user role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancancan

i'm currently working on building a site like freelancer using RoR, but i'm stuck somewhere, my user table which was generated with devise has a role column which can be admin, client or freelancer. Also i have a skills table which belongs to user but i don't want every user to have skills except from the users with the role of freelancer, how do i go about this, i'm currently using cancancan for user authorization and devise for authentication, is roles the best solution to this or STI and how would you advice me to approach this problem, here's an example code

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable,   :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :skills
  has_many :skills, through: :user_skills ## I don't want all users to have skills except the users with the role of freelancer
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles

  def role?(role)
    roles.any? { |r| r.name.underscore.to_sym == role }
  end

end
```

thank you in anticipation.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why was the question down voted?

Comment: You need to complement your question, see the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) help.

Comment: Please show the code you already wrote. Where are you stuck? What problem did you face?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, -> { where role: 'freelancer' }
end
```

Keep in mind that this would save the `skills` for any `role`, but they would be visible only for `freelancer`.
You could also use [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions) to check whether the user is a freelancer.